# mmenu HTTPS breaking the menu?

Tags: ssl, https, mmenu

On every site that I am using mmenu if the page is called via `http://` the menuing system works as expected - but if the same page/site is called using `https://` (SSL) it breaks the mmenu code - see attachments?

[Example of both views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHoeC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about mmenu but in general the cause might be if you are using static links like `http://example.com/page1.html` instead of relative URLs like `page1.html`.

However if you have to use static URLs then try writing it like:

```
<a href="//example.com/page1.html">my link</a>
```

because now using `//` mean both `http://` and `https://`